# Prevent input for Double byte characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I am trying to input only number and block rest of the character. here is my code

```html
<input type="number" maxlength="9" id="poisa" placeholder="依頼申請金額 :" name="budget" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57))">

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#poisa').on("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

it is working well when caps lock is not on. but when caps lock is on it is taking double byte character like `受取金額` i want to prevent this kinds of characters. How to do it by **jquery**?

Comment: why aren't you using a numeric input?

Comment: `<input type="number">`

Comment: You can try simple javascript : /^[0-9]+$/.test(input); which will return true if its purely numeric

Comment: Try : `<input type="number" onKeyUp="$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/ig, ''))" />`

Comment: Please don't advocate the use of just a simple `$(this).val(...` in a keyup - it completely breaks how the input works and stops you editing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "onKeyUp" should be something like :

```
<input type="number" maxlength="9" id="poisa" placeholder="依頼申請金額 :" name="budget" onKeyUp="$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/ig, ''))" />
```

Note : It will make the other inputs like alphabets or special characters, disappear if entered.

Comment: Please don't advocate the use of just a simple `$(this).val(...` in a keyup - it completely breaks how the input works and stops you editing values. eg if you have 123 but want 145 you would use the cursor keys to cursor over the the 2, but you can't as it's broken.  If you have 10 but want 1230 you would click between 1-0 and type 23 - you now have 1203 because of your broken sucky input

Comment: Although its true, but the number has a maxlength 9 so why do we need to go in-between of numbers using cursor to edit them ? We can simply backspace and erase the unwanted and retype the wanted number.

Comment: Back space and retype might be how you like to tediously, slowly edit your inputs, but not me.  100000000 oh, meant 123000000 - if you want to retype all that and risk adding the wrong number of zero's, fine.  I'd cursor-key across, delete 2 0s and type 23 as it's less prone to errors. I see this answer many times on SO and I think it provides a terrible UX, so will always highlight this.  If you don't care about your UX/users, then carry on.

Comment: Yeah absolutely i would like to be on the safer side and will backspace and retype the not-so-lengthy and not-so-time-consuming 9 digits, so as to make sure that i have entered the entire number correctly ! That is much of the care about my users, to have them enter correct inputs and thus ensuring the better UX.

Comment: Your solution is undoubtedly less prone to errors but mine don't have any ! So let people be the judge and decide which solution they should go through, The One with the possibility of prones to errors  (though less possibility) OR The One with the possibility of No Prone To Errors At All.

I am amazed what you might be doing if you've typed a wrong password and you don't have an "eye/visible pwd" button in an input. Will you go on the second or third dot using cursor and delete the wrong and type there again ? Oh, I will probably Retype the password by backsapcing it all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this. https://github.com/kenryanlabso/jquery-key-restrictions

```
$("#poisa").numbersOnly();
$("#poisa").lettersOnly();
$("#poisa").alphaNumericOnly();
```